# Execution order of select and group by in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT salary * months AS earnings, COUNT(*)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY earnings
ORDER BY earnings DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I have a doubt here, As per the order select is executed at last right, But here select is executed before group by, please provide some insight on this

Complete details refer this link

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem

Comment: Please provide more background on what you are trying to achieve. I am not sure what you goal is, maybe Partition by function could be of help - if you specific your request, we can help

Comment: Please refer to this link

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem

Comment: This link contains detailed description of the question @AlexanderP

Comment: Please let me know, if you need an other details @AlexanderP

Comment: Do not refer us to the problem description, post it into the question. Describe the task, not your attempt to solve it only.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: SQL Statements are not *executed* in any particular order.  They are compiled into something called a DAG which gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what SQL is.  A SQL `SELECT` statement *describes* the result set being produced.  It does not specify the steps for executing it.

That is, SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.

The `SELECT` statement is compiled, typically into a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of operations, which do get executed.  This has no obvious relation to the original `SELECT`.  For instance, there typically are not DAG operators called `SELECT`, `FROM`, or `WHERE`.  But the results are guaranteed to be the same.

You might be confused with scoping rules in the `SELECT` statement itself.  That is, table and column aliases are defined in the `FROM` and can be used throughout the query.  However, that is the scoping of the identifiers in the query, not any sort of "execution" order.